# Get the current numbers of CRAN packages and Bioconductor packages

Tags: r, bioconductor, cran

I am trying to insert the current number of CRAN packages and the number of Bioconductor packages to a markdown file.

I have tried this:

```
length(available.packages(available_packages_filters = c("CRAN")))
```

I got

```
[1] 272867
```

This is different from the number on the CRAN site (16081). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `available.packages` returns a matrix, you should count number of rows. `nrow(available.packages())`

Comment: @RonakShah, It works, thanks a lot. I got the correct number for CRAN. Any ideas about the number of Bioconductor?

Comment: ronak is right; please also be aware that there is likely some noise in this number, as the mirrors are not on a fixed syncing schedule, and the packages that are removed/added will not be reflected perfectly. I believe cran.r-project.org is to be considered the "main" copy. the situation should be similar for bioconductor bit I am less familiar

Comment: @MichaelChirico It's good to know. The number obtained on my machine was slightly different from that in RonakShah's answer. That is good enough for my purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`available.packages()` returns a matrix so you need to use `nrow` to get number of packages. However, as mentioned by @MichaelChirico note that the number might not be accurate as shown on the CRAN website because of syncing schedules.

```
CRANpackages <- available.packages()
nrow(CRANpackages)
#[1] 16068
```

As far as Bioconductor packages are concerned, I am not aware about a function which returns the number of packages but you can get the number from their website using this small scraping script.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/'
biocPackages <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_table() %>%.[[1]]
nrow(biocPackages)
#[1] 1905
```

Comment: Genius! I would never be able to work the Bioconductor number out myself. Thanks a lot, mate.